# How to extract a specific column from : ( colon ) separated values?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get the email portion of the following line:

```
                 ID:USERNAME:EMAIL:ADDRESS:OTHER
```

I just need a regex made to return the email and only the email.

How would I approach this? I keep getting only the ':'.

Comment: you aren't new to stackoverflow, your title isn't a question, you may wish to edit it.

Comment: heh, nope.....you need it to be a specific question

Comment: I edited to hopefully be a better question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option would probably be to just split the string and get the 3rd element from the resulting array. But you haven't said which programming language you're working in, so a purely regex solution would look something like the following, depending on the capabilities of the regex engine you have.

```
^[^:]+:[^:]+:([^:]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/VByUnI/1

This will start at the beginning of the input and match the email address in the first group.

If your regex flavor supports lookbehinds with non-fixed width, then this will give you an even cleaner result:

```
(?<=^[^:]+:[^:]+:)[^:]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/VByUnI/2

The only text matched will be the email address.

Comment: Thank you! The first line worked!

edit; the second one too =]

Answer (score 0):

This one was tricky. Try this regex.

```
:\w+:(\w+):
```

It should work. I tested it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QqpFma/1).

What's happening is that although you match ":USERNAME:EMAIL:", you only extract the email portion using the parenthesis.

**Update:** This won't work as JDBstillremembersMonica pointed out in the comments, \w only matches [a-zA-Z0-9_] so the `@` in the email address would not get matched.

Comment: Thanks for helping but however It didn't return anything for me :/

Comment: This probably won't work because `\w` typically only matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. It would not, for example, match the `@` in an email address. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`(?:.+:){2}(.+)(?::.+){2}`

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GvjNjo/1)

This will capture any characters in the `EMAIL` field.  You can be more deliberate by subsituting `(.+)` with an email-specific pattern which you can find all over the web.

Comment: This worked for one of the cases but not all :/